# Angular.mock.$interval.flush() throws strange exception

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angular-mock

I have created the following small controller for testing that the interval function is triggered at the specified interval

```
angular.module('app').controller('myTstController', [
'$interval', function($interval) {
    var called = 0;
    $interval(function() {
        called++;
    }, 10);
    this.getCalled = function() { return called; }
}
]);
```

The spec:

```
it('should call getSystemMessages on an interval', function() {
    var ctrl, $interval;
    angular.mock.module('app');
    angular.mock.inject(function($controller, _$interval_) {
        $interval = _$interval_;

        ctrl = $controller('myTstController', {$interval: $interval});

    });
    expect(ctrl.getCalled()).toEqual(0);
    $interval.flush(10);
    expect(ctrl.getCalled()).toEqual(1);
});
```

Jasmine throws following error:

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET app/login/login.html
No more request expected
at $httpBackend (http://localhost:39474/Scripts/angular-mocks.js:1175:5)
at sendReq (http://localhost:39474/Scripts/angular.js:7817:9)
at serverRequest (http://localhost:39474/Scripts/angular.js:7551:9)
at wrappedCallback (http://localhost:39474/Scripts/angular.js:10965:15)
at Anonymous function (http://localhost:39474/Scripts/angular.js:11051:11)
at Scope.prototype.$eval (http://localhost:39474/Scripts/angular.js:11977:9)
at Scope.prototype.$digest (http://localhost:39474/Scripts/angular.js:11803:15)
at Scope.prototype.$apply (http://localhost:39474/Scripts/angular.js:12083:13)
at tick (http://localhost:39474/Scripts/angular-mocks.js:497:25)
at $interval.flush (http://localhost:39474/Scripts/angular-mocks.js:546:9)
```

For me it looks like we are getting an error that redirects the application to the loginpage, but based on our code I cannot understand why this should happen? if I use flush < 10 it will fail as expected on the last expect statement.

Does anyone know what is going on or what we are doing wrong in this case?

Comment: Is there any other code in the controller or the module ? How are you running the tests ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem. I have identified the culprit and it is following code in our module:    app.run(['$route', function (route) {
        //include $route to kickstart the router
    }]);

Comment: Injecting $httpBackend and mocking $httpBackend.expectGET('app/login/login.html').respond(200); solved the issue. Also needed to include a service in specRunner.html. This service I cannot see how it is involved as since it is not a dependency in the loginController. I would like to know why I have to inject the $httpBackend in this case, but not for other controllers that we test and why other tests for our controller worked fine before I added $interval.flush

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injecting `$httpBackend` and mocking

```
$httpBackend.expectGET('app/login/login.html').respond(200);
```

solved the issue!